# .weak assembler macro for MinGW GCC / C alternative

Tags: c, assembly, macros, weak

I have a modular C-Project with some different libraries/objects, which are only linked to the release if some conditions are met. This project is build with GCC 3.4.4 for PowerPC.

So all over my project there are some C-Files which use functions from other modules (these modules are not necessearily added to the build). So these functions are declared as extern.

Depending on the release, the module containing the function itself is linked or not. To avoid the undefined references, these functions are declared as weak with an assembler macro.

I aam trying to show this with an example:

**ModuleA.c (Core Module)**

```
extern void bar(void);
void foo(void)
{
    // Do some Stuff    
    bar();
}
```

**ModuleB.c (Optional Module)**

```
void bar(void)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

ModuleB is not always linked to ModuleA, only in some specific Release Builds. So there is a third C-File

**weakfuncs.c (Core Module)**

```
#define WEAK(x,y) __asm__(".weak " #x "\n.set " #x "," #y "\n");
void empty_function(void);
__asm__("empty_function:\nblr\n");
WEAK(bar,empty_function)
```

With this Macro, the project always builds (If ModuleB is linked, `bar()` will be called from ModuleB, if not ModuleB is not linked, `bar()` will just call `empty_function()`.

Since there are a lot of these cases all over the project my predecessor was collecting all these functions in the `weakfuncs.c`.

**So far this was legacy code I am just reusing**

Now I want to compile the whole thing for Windows with MinGW (GCC 4.8.1).
My problem is that the compiler seems to have problems with the assembler directives:

```
__asm__("empty_function:\nblr\n");
```

Is not working at all (He doesnt know the `blr` command), but this is not an issue, since I can just implement an empty function in C like this:

```
void empty_function(void)
{
    return;
}
```

The WEAK macro itself

```
#define WEAK(x,y) __asm__(".weak " #x "\n.set " #x "," #y "\n");
```

compiles without problems but it has no effect, meaning, the functions which are not linked wil cause "undefined reference", even tho I did run the WEAK macro over them.

Now I know there is a way in gcc to give the function the attribute weak like this:

```
extern void bar() __attribute__((weak));
```

This actually works, but since there are a lot of functions which would all need the adaption I would prefer to do it in my `weakfuncs.c` with a macro.

Is there any assembler directive or a way in C to do so, without chaning all function declerations all over the placE?

Comment: The function should be `b lr` with a space for the ARM CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
void empty_function(void)
{
    return;
}
#define WEAK(x,y) extern void x() __attribute__((weak, alias(#y)));
```

Comment: This does unfortunately not work - I actually don't know why, but I think it's related to the fact, that the function is one time declared in the Module file (e.g. `ModuleA.c`) itself, just as extern and then again in the weakfuncs - the assembler code instead does change the attribute of the symbol.

Comment: @Toby: Oh! It looks like it is a known [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9687) in the MingW linker. Please try the updated answer as a workaround, which is actually more close to the original code.

Comment: This doesn't work either, I still get the undefined reference error. I am not sure but I think the problem is related to the fact that the function is defined in `ModuleA.c` with `extern void bar(void)`. Now I don't know why there is no explicit error about this, but the makro you suggested , does it make a difference? Because `bar()` is already declared...so...?